# Postgres escaping backslash in SIMILAR TO syntax

Tags: postgresql

I have table containing 4 lines as follow:

```
Audit\\subfolder\System2.log
Audit\\subfolder/System1.log
Audit\\System2.log
Audit\\System1.log
```

Running the following query:

> select *  from table where file_location SIMILAR TO
>   'Audit\\[^/]*'

will yield:

```
Audit\\subfolder\System2.log
Audit\\System2.log
Audit\\System1.log
```

However running the following query:

> select * from table where file_location SIMILAR TO
>   'Audit\\[^\\]*'

yields me nothing.

What would be the correct way to escape `\\` in `SIMILAR TO` clause?

Comment: `SIMILAR TO` is IMO a waste of time. Just use a perl-compatible regex with `~`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *What would be the correct way to escape \ in SIMILAR TO clause?*

Using `ESCAPE` might be a natural choice:

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE file_location SIMILAR TO 'Audit\\[^!\]*' ESCAPE '!'
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a7251/10)** demo

Comment: weird that it didn't work on first try, but it works now, thanks